# Tensorflow: value error with variable_scope in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

This is my code in tensorflow to train a GAN. I am training des to able to distinguish between fake and original video. I have important not relevant part of code to avoid stack over flow mostly code error

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28])

D_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([1024, 128]))
D_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

D_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([128, 1]))
D_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1]))


theta_D = [D_W1, D_W2, D_b1, D_b2]

rnn_size = 1024
rnn_layer = 2


Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 100])

G_W1 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([100, 128]))
G_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[128]))

G_W2 = tf.Variable(xavier_init([128, 784]))
G_b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[784]))

theta_G = [G_W1, G_W2, G_b1, G_b2]


def sample_Z(m, n):
    return np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[m, n])


def generator(z):
    G_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(z, G_W1) + G_b1)
    G_log_prob = tf.matmul(G_h1, G_W2) + G_b2
    G_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(G_log_prob)
    G_prob = tf.reshape(G_prob, [-1,28, 28])
    return G_prob

def discriminator(x):

    x = [tf.squeeze(t, [1]) for t in tf.split(x, 28, 1)]

    # with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'):
    stacked_rnn1 = []
    for iiLyr1 in range(rnn_layer):
        stacked_rnn1.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True))
    lstm_multi_fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=stacked_rnn1)

    # with tf.variable_scope('rnn_def'):
    dec_outputs, dec_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
        lstm_multi_fw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    D_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(dec_outputs[-1], D_W1) + D_b1)
    D_logit = tf.matmul(D_h1, D_W2) + D_b2

    D_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(D_logit)

    return D_prob, D_logit

G_sample = generator(Z)

print(G_sample.get_shape())
print(X.get_shape())
D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X)
D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

D_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real) + tf.log(1. - D_fake))
G_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_fake))

summary_d = tf.summary.histogram('D_loss histogram', D_loss)


summary_g = tf.summary.histogram('D_loss histogram', G_loss)


summary_s = tf.summary.scalar('D_loss scalar', D_loss)

summary_s1 = tf.summary.scalar('scalar scalar', G_loss)




# Add image summary
summary_op = tf.summary.image("plot", image)

D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss, var_list=theta_D)
G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss, var_list=theta_G)

mb_size = 128
Z_dim = 100

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

sess = tf.Session()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

writer1 = tf.summary.FileWriter('log/log-sample1', sess.graph)

writer2 = tf.summary.FileWriter('log/log-sample2', sess.graph)


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

if not os.path.exists('out/'):
    os.makedirs('out/')

i = 0


with tf.variable_scope("myrnn") as scope:

    for it in range(5000):



        X_mb, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(mb_size)
        X_mb = tf.reshape(X_mb, [mb_size, -1, 28])

        _, D_loss_curr = sess.run([D_solver, D_loss], feed_dict={X: X_mb, Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})
        _, G_loss_curr = sess.run([G_solver, G_loss], feed_dict={Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})


        summary_str, eded = sess.run([summary_d, summary_s], feed_dict={X: X_mb, Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})
        writer1.add_summary(summary_str, it)

        writer1.add_summary(eded, it)

        summary_str1, eded1 = sess.run([summary_g, summary_s1], feed_dict={X: X_mb, Z: sample_Z(mb_size, Z_dim)})
        writer2.add_summary(summary_str1, it)

        writer2.add_summary(eded1, it)


        if it % 1000 == 0:
            print('Iter: {}'.format(it))
            print('D loss: {:.4}'. format(D_loss_curr))
            print('G_loss: {:.4}'.format(G_loss_curr))
            print()
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    writer1.close()
    writer2.close()
`
```

Following is the error when I run this code please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tulsijain/Desktop/Deep Learning Practise/GAN/vanila.py", line 104, in <module>
    D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample)
  File "/Users/tulsijain/Desktop/Deep Learning Practise/GAN/vanila.py", line 64, in discriminator
    lstm_multi_fw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 1212, in static_rnn
    (output, state) = call_cell()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 1199, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 916, in call
    cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 180, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 441, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 383, in call
    concat = _linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1017, in _linear
    initializer=kernel_initializer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1065, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 962, in get_variable
    use_resource=use_resource, custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 360, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape, use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1405, in wrapped_custom_getter
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 183, in _rnn_get_variable
    variable = getter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 352, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 664, in _get_single_variable
    name, "".join(traceback.format_list(tb))))
ValueError: Variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/Users/tulsijain/Desktop/Deep Learning Practise/GAN/vanila.py", line 64, in discriminator
    lstm_multi_fw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/Users/tulsijain/Desktop/Deep Learning Practise/GAN/vanila.py", line 103, in <module>
    D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X)
```

It is GAN. I am using MNIST data to train generator and discriminator.

Comment: D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample) part of coe is responsible for throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `reuse` parameter to the `BasicLSTMCell`. Since you are calling the `discriminator` function twice and calling `reuse=None`, both the times, it throws the errors when try to create variables with same name. In this context you need to reuse the variables from the graph for the second call; as you don't need to create new set of variables.

```
def discriminator(x, reuse):

    x = [tf.squeeze(t, [1]) for t in tf.split(x, 28, 1)]

    # with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'):
    stacked_rnn1 = []
    for iiLyr1 in range(rnn_layer):
        stacked_rnn1.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True, reuse=reuse))
    lstm_multi_fw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=stacked_rnn1)

    # with tf.variable_scope('rnn_def'):
    dec_outputs, dec_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
         lstm_multi_fw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    D_h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(dec_outputs[-1], D_W1) + D_b1)
    D_logit = tf.matmul(D_h1, D_W2) + D_b2

    D_prob = tf.nn.sigmoid(D_logit)

    return D_prob, D_logit
....
D_real, D_logit_real = discriminator(X, None)
D_fake, D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample, True)
....
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Could you please explain this in more details or point me to some source ?

Comment: about variable sharing you can follow this link https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope.

Comment: Apart from that; in a general GAN architecture, discriminator parameters for real and fake sample should be same, so you need to share parameters when calculating logits for real/fake samples.